# How should you go about self-studying advanced graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory, self-learning, advice

So I have become familiar with the basics. I have read both GRAPH THEORY WITH APPLICATIONS by Bondy and murty and Richard J. Trudeau - Introduction to Graph Theory. How do  I take graph theory to the next level. Any resources or recommendations?

Also how to get into the research field and start a research path in graph theory?

Comment: I used Algebraic Graph Theory by Godsil and Royle. I never did any research in graph theory, though. You should probably consult the references and start reading some research. Ideally, you would have an advisor to help you start on a research path. Graph theory is cool in that it doesn't require extensive technical knowledge to get into.